# Remote anonymous access to repository denied?

Tags: git, github

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and just upgraded my `git` from `1.7`-something to version `1.8.4`. The problem is when I want to push to a GitHub repository, I get the following message and the push doesn't happen:

```
/caniuse $ git push
Username for 'https://github.com': rafalchmiel
Password for 'https://rafalchmiel@github.com': 
remote: Anonymous access to rafalchmiel/caniuse.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/rafalchmiel/caniuse.git/'
```

This is what I get from `git config --list`:

```
user.name=Rafal Chmiel
user.email=rafalmarekchmiel@gmail.com
alias.undo-commit=reset --soft HEAD^
color.ui=true
push.default=matching
credential.helper=cache --timeout=86400
github.user=rafalchmiel
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/rafalchmiel/caniuse.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

And these are my remotes (`git remote -v`):

```
origin  https://github.com/rafalchmiel/caniuse.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/rafalchmiel/caniuse.git (push)
```

I tried setting up the SSH keys again (although this is done through HTTP) and have search for options. No luck. Any ideas on what else I could do?

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried changing the remote to use the SSH link?

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, I tried it out and it worked straight away. I'm dumping HTTPS for good! SSH FTW.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issues was not resolved however in the end I decided to go with SSH instead of HTTPS. SSH caused *no* problems at all (and there's no need to type in the username and pass)!

Comment: +2, really, after having lost quite some time, this solved it!

Comment: SSH causes other problems to me.

Comment: Great, except my organisation blocks port 22, so SSH is not an option :-(. @xtopolis' answer below (Personal Access Tokens) works though :-)

Comment: @raf I'm posting an answer now that will hopefully help people if they want to post with SSH

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue due to the fact that I had 2-Factor-Auth enabled, and the password it was asking for was the generated password / personal access token, not my LDAP password. I didn't remember that I had set it up at the time.

Creating a Personal Access Token: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/ , allowed me to push successfully using the generated token as a password.

Context: Internally hosted Enterprise Github. Able to clone, enabled as a collaborator, but unable to push origin master.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot xtopolis. My context is slightly different to yours: I have  2-Factor-Auth enabled, but I'm using IntelliJ 2017.2.5 on Linux instead. Thanks again, Orlando.

Answer (score 4):

I also face this issue and as @xtopolis have mentioned I generated a access token as mentioned in this article https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

Then pushed changes with following command

```
git push https://<ACCESS_TOCKEN>@github.com/username/repo_name.git
```

Comment: This works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and got to this question in the search for an answer.

Figured out the issue.

1. Using the command `git push` without adding any files can give this error
2. Using the command `git push` without adding any commits can do the same

so the simple solution would be to follow this

```
git add --all .
git commit
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your SSH key, you must use the following format:

```
$ <snip> on MBP-0x00A3 in ~/misc/vim_dotfiles
✭ (git) working on branch alternate ✔
❯❯ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/<snip>/vim_dotfiles.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<snip>/vim_dotfiles.git (push)

$ <snip> on MBP-0x00A3 in ~/misc/vim_dotfiles
✭ (git) working on branch alternate ✔
❯❯ git remote add personal git@github.com:<snip>/vim_dotfiles.git

$ <snip> on MBP-0x00A3 in ~/misc/vim_dotfiles
✭ (git) working on branch alternate ✔
❯❯ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/<snip>/vim_dotfiles.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<snip>/vim_dotfiles.git (push)
personal    git@github.com:<snip>/vim_dotfiles.git (fetch)
personal    git@github.com:<snip>/vim_dotfiles.git (push)
```

Now you can do:

```
user@host:~$ git push personal <branch>
```

and it will force use of your SSH key.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. But A little different with you.

```
Username for 'https://www.github.com': xxxx@gmail.com
Password for 'https://xxxx@gmail.com@www.github.com':
remote: Anonymous access to xxxxx.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://www.github.com/yyyy/xxx
```

And I found the cause of problem is that I clone with the prefix of **www** `https://www.github.com/yyyy/xxx`

I solved it by git clone the repository again like this `https://github.com/yyyy/xxx`, and everything go right.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about the cause, but I solved this issue by using git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git instead of https.