# Github: Anonymous access to repo denied

Tags: git, github

I can't seem to find any duplicates so here we go:

I'm struggling pushing changes to my git repository. I now have several commits waiting to be pushed but I keep getting the error:

> remote: Anonymous access to #repo denied.
>
> fatal: Authentication failed for '#repo'

I've masked my repo.

I have a pretty aggressive firewall here at work but our network engineer has a direct IP for the proxy (so I don't have to use a PAC file).

I set it up using the following:

```
git config --global https.proxy xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:80
```

and now I can clone a repo fine! I can't however, push changes to this repo I get the above error.

I've tried my password 100 times, I've logged out, and back in.

I've set up a personal access token and tried to use that, same error.

**My work blocks all traffic on port 22 so SSH is out of the question!**

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I can clone a repo fine but can't push to it? What does anonymous access mean and how can I become 'nymous' - aka. Where do I log my details?

I've removed all credential.helper caches etc.

**EDIT:** my [Config - PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ugE3FHu5)

**OUTPUTS:**
Clone:

```
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\GitHub> git clone htt
t
Cloning into 'test'...
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 1), reused 7 (delta 1),
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Remote -v:

```
C:\Users\mshiner\Desktop\GitHub\test [master =]> git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/Me/test.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Me/test.git (push)
```

Repo push:

```
C:\Users\mshiner\Desktop\GitHub\test [master =]> git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': #username
Password for 'https://me@github.com':
remote: Anonymous access to me/test.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/me/test.git/'
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you cloned this repo via `ssh` or `https` ?

Comment: Must be https, all ssh traffic is blocked.

Comment: What exactly does your `git clone` command look like?  What is the output of `git remote -v`?  What is the output of `git push`?

Comment: I've added all outputs to the commands I've used, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [SSH over the HTTPS port](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/)?

Comment: Is two-factor authentication enabled on your github account?

Comment: Have you tried to add some files and commit them before pushing? This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22683901/390808 suggests that this error happens when you push without making any changes.